# Combiné dos matrices de nombres en una sola pero cuando la imprimo no me salen los últimos nombres

Tags: java

El método *Fusionar* me combina lista1 y lista2 en una la lista3 y utilizo `compareTo` para poder organizarlas por orden pero cuando en la lista2 llega a Josefina se empieza a repetir el proceso e ignora los demás nombres, no sé el porqué.

```
public class CFusionarListas {
  
    public static int Fusionar(String[] listaA, String[] listaB, String[] listaC){
         int ind =0, indA =0, indB =0, indC=0;
        
        if (listaA.length + listaB.length ==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        //Fusionar las listas A y B en la C
        while(indA < listaA.length && indB < listaB.length)
            if (listaA[indA].compareTo(listaB[indB]) <0)
              listaC[indC++] = listaA[indA++];
            else
              listaC[indC++] = listaB[indB++];
            
        //Los dos bucles siguientes son para prever el caso de que, lógicamente una lista 
          finalizará antes que la otra.
        for (ind = indA; ind < listaA.length; ind++) 
            listaC[indC++] = listaA[ind];
        for (ind = indB; ind < listaB.length; ind++) 
            listaC[indC++] = listaA[ind];
            
            return 1;
         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lista1 = {"Ana", "Carmen", "David", "Francisco", "Javier", "Jesús",
                 "José", "Josefina", "Luis", "María", "Patricia", "Sonia"};
        
        String[] lista2 = {"Augustin", "Belén","Daniel", "Fernando", "Manuel", "Pedro",
         "Rosa", "Susana", "Tatiana", "Victor"};
        String[] lista3 = new String[lista1.length + lista2.length];
        
        int ind, r;
        r = Fusionar(lista1, lista2, lista3);
        
        if (r !=0) {
            for (ind = 0; ind < lista3.length; ind++) 
                System.out.println(lista3[ind]);
                } 
        else
            System.out.println("Error");
   
    }
    
}
```

Comment: tambien podrias hacer uso de [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) como alternativa `String[] lista3 =Stream.of(lista1, lista2).flatMap(Stream::of).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: Lo cambio por el método Fusionar?

Comment: Reemplaza todo tu método, es una alternativa más corta

Answer (score 1):

Es un simple typo. En el método `Fusionar`, tenés que cambiar la anteúltima línea que dice esto:

```
listaC[indC++] = listaA[ind];
```

por esto

```
listaC[indC++] = listaB[ind];
```

que es la razón por la cual parece repetirse el proceso.

Comment: Rato después me di cuenta, gracias!!